# Webpack imports-loader with coffeescript

Tags: webpack, coffeescript, imports-loader

I've a legacy application written in coffeescript and want to use webpack to bundle the project.

The goal is to use webpack without impacting the current code.

I've global functions in file ***functions.coffee*** that is used all over the application. Now I want to compile the project without using import in each module.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

I tried using imports-loader like below:

```
module: {
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.coffee$/,
    loader: 'coffee-loader'
  },
  {
    test: require.resolve("./src/coffee/functions.coffee"),
    use: "imports-loader?this=>window"
  }
 ]
}
```

However, it seems that imports-loader doesn't recognize Coffeescript. I get the following error:

```
error: regular expressions cannot begin with *
/*** IMPORTS FROM imports-loader ***/
^
L0: /*** IMPORTS FROM imports-loader ***/
```